# sending mail using pear

Tags: pear

I have installed pear and when sending mail, I get the following error:
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 6144 bytes) in C:\wamp\www\GamesRus\mail.php on line 2

I am running on windows 7.
Here is my code:

"me@example.com", "Subject"=>"Test Mail");

    $body = "This is a test!";

    $mail->send("jngichabe@yahoo.com", $headers, $body);

?>

I would really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the memory_limit in your php.ini; considering 128MB of memory has been exhausted, I'd suggest a nice round number such as 256MB.

so change the entry in your php.ini to:
memory_limit = 256M ;

Comment: Just tried that but it didnt work. It exhausts 256 bytes plus a few more.